# call a java function when we press browser close button

Tags: javascript

how we can call a java function when we press browser close button...mins when when we close the browser...

Answer (score 3):

You can't tell from JavaScript when the browser window gets closed. The closest you can get is the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event that is supported by all major browsers and will fire when the current page gets unloaded - that can have a lot of reasons though, e.g. a simple navigating away to the next or previous page.

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke js based on a non DOM element's event, *the browser buttons that is*.